# Open Report if field contains certain word

Tags: ms-access, report

We have a form with 2 buttons pointing to 2 reports, ideally we would like one button on the form to prevent user printing incorrect certificates

Is there a way to have only one button so when a user clicks on the button to run a report, that

> if [type] contains "semi" open report "semi cert" & if [type] contains "spring" open report "spring cert"

these are our currents buttons

```vb
Private Sub semi_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Quick Hitch (SEMI) Certificate", acViewPreview, , "[no] = " & Me.[no]
    DoCmd.PrintOut
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub spring_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Quick Hitch (SPRING) Certificate", acViewPreview, , "[no] = " & Me.[no]
    DoCmd.PrintOut
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `type` is the name of your text box

```vb
Private Sub OpenReport_Click()
    Dim reportName As String

    Select Case Me.[type].Value
        Case "semi"
            reportName = "Quick Hitch (SEMI) Certificate"
        Case "spring"
            reportName = "Quick Hitch (SPRING) Certificate"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Report type '" & Me.[type].Value & "'is unknown"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    DoCmd.OpenReport reportName , acViewPreview, , "[no] = " & Me.[no]
    DoCmd.PrintOut
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```